# Why does ICollection<T> interface inherit both IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, collections

I've read an article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx

They specify here that `ICollection<T>` derives from the two aforementioned interfaces. But why not simply inherit `IEnumerable<T>`? It already derives from the other (the `IEnumerable` one). So why do we inherit it once more? I don't understand...

Comment: MSDN is documentation, not the source.

Comment: One possible reason could be that `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` existed long before `IEnumerable<T>` appeared. It's always like that in application development - new things appear and you don't won't to break the existing code in any way...

Comment: No, I mean that we already have all the necessary behavior in 'IEnumerable<T>' as it inherits 'IEnumerable'. If we erase 'IEnumerable' from the list of inherited by 'ICollection<T>' interfaces, we, as far as I know, get the same result. So why being extra?

Comment: Just look at the source code, not MSDN: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/icollection.cs

Comment: `IEnumerable` is listed on MSDN for exposition purposes, the source code, as mentioned above, doesn't list `IEnumerable` twice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is more for backward compatibility with .NET1.0 when there was only IEnumerable. So a client which is still in older version will not be broken.